# Multiple Dispatch Swift attempt: Conflicting arguments to generic parameter 'T' ('Cat' vs. 'Dog')

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, multiple-dispatch

I was watching a video on Julia about Multiple Dispatch and was curious if I could write something similar in Swift. I see that Swift relies on the compiler where Julia seems to determine a type at run time, but I also discovered something I don't understand about Swift.

Why would the below function `encounters` work when the 2 parameters are of the same type of Pet but not when one is a Cat and the other is a Dog?

For example the two functions below work

```
encounters(Arturo, Gabby) // both Cat
encounters(Cc, Bb) // both Dog
```

but these give a compiler error

> Conflicting arguments to generic parameter 'T' ('Cat' vs. 'Dog')

```
encounters(Arturo, Bb) // Cat and Dog
encounters(Bb, Arturo) // Dog and Cat
```

```
protocol Pet: Equatable {
    var name: String { get }
}
struct Cat: Pet {
    let name: String
}
struct Dog: Pet {
    let name: String
}

let Arturo = Cat(name: "Arturo")
let Gabby = Cat(name: "Gabby")
let Bb = Dog(name: "Bb")
let Cc = Dog(name: "Cc")

func encounters<T: Pet>(_ a: T, _ b: T) {
    var verb: String
    switch (a, b) {
    case is (Cat, Dog):
        verb = meet(a as! Cat, b as! Dog)
    case is (Dog, Dog):
        verb = meet(a as! Dog, b as! Dog)
    case is (Cat, Cat):
        verb = meet(a as! Cat, b as! Cat)
    case is (Dog, Cat):
        verb = meet(a as! Dog, b as! Cat)
        
    default:
        fatalError()
    }
    
    print("\(a.name) meets \(b.name) and \(verb)")
}

func meet(_ a: Cat, _ b: Cat) -> String {
    return "Slinks"
}

func meet(_ a: Cat, _ b: Dog) -> String {
    return "Hisses"
}

func meet(_ a: Dog, _ b: Dog) -> String {
    return "Howles"
}

func meet(_ a: Dog, _ b: Cat) -> String {
    return "Barks"
}
```

Comment: The use of generics is unnecessary in this example, you could simply do `func encounters(_ a: Pet, _ b: Pet)` if you're going to compare it against explicit types anyway.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I did try that first but I get the error `Protocol 'Pet' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Comment: That's because you added `:Equatable` to the protocol, which in most cases is not what you mean. That means that the conforming types must themselves be Equatable. It does not mean that Pet itself is Equatable. Protocols cannot conform to other protocols, so it is not possible for Pet to be Equatable. You don't rely on Equatable in this code anyway.

Comment: Note that the need to add a `fatalError()` default is a clue that you're on the wrong track here and fighting the language. There are cases where `fatalError` is appropriate, but in this case it's showing that you've wandered outside the types system, and are checking things at runtime that are expected to be checked at compile time. If you added a Snake type of Pet (which could be added in a completely different module, for example), this code would crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not take this approach, but the reason it doesn't work is because you attached Equatable to Pet. You probably meant something like "Pets should be comparable to other Pets," but that's not what that means. It means that types that conform to Pet must themselves be Equatable. If you remove Equatable, this works as written without the generic as Claus notes:

```
protocol Pet { ... }
func encounters(_ a: Pet, _ b: Pet) { ... }
```

So much `as!` makes Swift devs nervous and is unnecessary. The `as!` isn't wrong, but it opens the door for easy mistakes that the compiler can't catch. This style lets the compiler help you a little more. It still won't be able to catch missing cases.

```
func encounters(_ a: Pet, _ b: Pet) {
    var verb: String
    switch (a, b) {
    case let (a as Cat, b as Dog):
        verb = meet(a, b)
    case let (a as Dog, b as Dog):
        verb = meet(a, b)
    case let (a as Cat, b as Cat):
        verb = meet(a, b)
    case let (a as Dog, b as Cat):
        verb = meet(a, b)

    default:
        fatalError()
    }

    print("\(a.name) meets \(b.name) and \(verb)")
}
```

I definitely do not like the `fatalError` here. Both this code and the Julia I assume you've written would crash if some new Pet were created. That's not very good. But I assume it's not a major part of this question. In Swift, you'd put something in the default leg. In Julia, you'd add a more general multimethod for `meet(a::Pet, b::Pet)`.

If there really are only the two possible Pets, then you really should be thinking about enums instead of dynamic dispatch, but again I assume that's not the question.

Like I said, I don't really like this approach. I think it's very verbose, and adds a lot of places for mistakes. If you want this kind of dynamic type lookup, I'd do dynamic type lookup in data.

```
struct Meeting {
    let lhs: Pet.Type
    let rhs: Pet.Type
    let verb: String

    func matches(_ lhs: Pet, _ rhs: Pet) -> Bool {
        self.lhs == type(of: lhs) && self.rhs == type(of: rhs)
    }
}

let meetings = [
    Meeting(lhs: Cat.self, rhs: Dog.self, verb: "Hisses"),
    Meeting(lhs: Dog.self, rhs: Dog.self, verb: "Howles"),
    Meeting(lhs: Cat.self, rhs: Cat.self, verb: "Slinks"),
    Meeting(lhs: Dog.self, rhs: Cat.self, verb: "Barks"),
]

func encounters(_ a: Pet, _ b: Pet) {
    let verb = meetings
        .first(where: { $0.matches(a, b) })?.verb
        ?? "passes by"
    print("\(a.name) meets \(b.name) and \(verb)")
}
```

Even if you need functions, you can expand this to storing functions as data (which is an incredibly powerful way of implementing dynamic dispatch).

Instead of just a verb, add an action function to Meeting:

```
struct Meeting {
    let lhs: Pet.Type
    let rhs: Pet.Type
    let action: (Pet) -> String  // Function that takes a Pet and gives a String

    func matches(_ lhs: Pet, _ rhs: Pet) -> Bool {
        self.lhs == type(of: lhs) && self.rhs == type(of: rhs)
    }
}
```

Now it's starting to look more like your multi-methods, putting all the specialized logic in one place:

```
let meetings = [
    Meeting(lhs: Cat.self, rhs: Dog.self, action: { "Hisses at \($0.name)" }),
    Meeting(lhs: Dog.self, rhs: Dog.self, action: { "Howles at \($0.name)" }),
    Meeting(lhs: Cat.self, rhs: Cat.self, action: { _ in "Slinks by" }),
    Meeting(lhs: Dog.self, rhs: Cat.self, action: { "Barks at \($0.name)" }),
]
```

And `encounters` calls it:

```
func encounters(_ a: Pet, _ b: Pet) {
    let action = meetings
        .first(where: { $0.matches(a, b) })?.action
        ?? { _ in "passes by" }

    let verb = action(b)
    
    print("\(a.name) meets \(b.name) and \(verb)")
}
```

It's not completely as powerful as multimethods, but it's easier to reason about the type safety at compile-time.

Comment: Thanks Rob! I agree, it definitely felt uncomfortable type casting everything in the switch statement and using fatalError. In Julia is doesn't need a switch statement or anything like that, it's able to determine which pets are in the parameters (I assume at run time) and use the correct overloaded method for the appropriate animal. Adding new animals are pretty easy in Julia as you just need to create another animal type and then another method overload for that animal. But I like your dynamic type look up in data approach. Too bad Swift doesn't support multiple dispatch!

Comment: In Julia, at least in all my experiments, if you add another Pet and fail to add a dispatch function, it'll crash at runtime. It basically has an implicit `fatalError`. You just can't see it. That's the major difference, and something Swift actively is trying to avoid. In Julia you *can* add a default `Pet` multimethod, but if you don't, it won't catch it. (Note that Julia is great for interactive development, where a crash is not such a big deal. You see it, you fix it, move on. But a crash in an iOS app is much harder to find out about, let alone fix.)

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to create a generic function with a type that conforms to a protocol then you need to use that protocol all the way, you can't use conforming types inside the function since any custom type can be made to conform to the protocol.

Here is an example solution using the protocol only

```
protocol Pet {
    var name: String { get }
    var same: String { get }
    var other: String { get }
}
```

Cat and Dog conforming to the protocol

```
struct Cat: Pet {
    var name: String
    var other: String { "Slinks" }
    var same: String { "Hisses" }
}
struct Dog: Pet {
    let name: String
    var other: String { "Barks" }
    var same: String { "Howles" }
}
```

and then the function becomes

```
func encounters<T: Pet, U: Pet>(_ a: T, _ b: U) {
    let verb: String
    if T.self == U.self {
        verb = a.same
    } else {
        verb = a.other
    }
    print("\(a.name) meets \(b.name) and \(verb)")
}
```

example

```
let arturo = Cat(name: "Arturo")
let gabby = Cat(name: "Gabby")
let bb = Dog(name: "Bb")
let cc = Dog(name: "Cc")

encounters(arturo, bb)
encounters(bb, arturo)
encounters(gabby, arturo)
encounters(cc, bb)
```

> Arturo meets Bb and Slinks
> Bb meets Arturo and Barks
> Gabby meets Arturo and Hisses
> Cc meets Bb and Howles

Comment: Thanks Joakim, the only thing with this approach is that if we add more animals the "other" might need to be different depending on the animals.

Comment: If a cat for instance makes a different sound when it meats a mouse than if it meets a dog then you would need either specific methods for each with (mouse: Mouse) and (dog: Dog) parameters respectively or a more general (pet: Pet) but this one needs to contain all animal types and neither of them will be generic